# Difference between std::iterator, std::iterator_traits, std::random_access_iterator_tag

Tags: c++, iterator, c++98, iterator-traits

I need to write my own iterator (a random access one) for my custom container. And it is required to re-implement `iterator_traits` as well.

I know that [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is a base class for [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). They are both **classes**. Whereas [`std::random_access_iterator_tag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) is a **struct**.

My first attempt is something like this: (example of [this link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/))

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator, std::input_iterator_tag

class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_tag, int>
{
  int* p;
public:
  MyIterator(int* x) :p(x) {}
  MyIterator(const MyIterator& mit) : p(mit.p) {}
  MyIterator& operator++() {++p;return *this;}
  MyIterator operator++(int) {MyIterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  bool operator==(const MyIterator& rhs) const {return p==rhs.p;}
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs) const {return p!=rhs.p;}
  int& operator*() {return *p;}
};
```

But then I don't know where to put `iterator_traits` into the picture? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you say which C++ version you're targeting? Or add the corresponding tag.

Comment: Please check [this `std::iterator` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). It has been deprecated since the C++17 standard.

Comment: `iterator_traits` will magically work when your iterator type inherits from `std::iterator`, you don't need to provide it. But note that `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17 which means you shouldn't use it anymore. You need to define the members manually for your iterator type, but if you do it correctly `iterator_traits` will still keep working for your iterator type automatically.

Comment: Also see [this itrator tag reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) to see an example on how to use them together with [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). Do note that these are used for [legacy iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator).

Comment: *"They are both **classes**"* you seems to give importance between class and struct, but in C++, it is the same except for default visibility.

Comment: Lastly, legacy iterators are defined by the available operations on them, nothing more. A random access iterator can perform a certain set of operations, and those operations are what makes it a random access iterator. So you don't need `std::iterator`, `std::random_access_iterator_tag` or `std::iterator_traits`. All you need is to overload the required functions and operators for a [legacy random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Comment: @BrianBi: I need to do in c++98.

Comment: @Jarod42: I had no idea that they are the same for C++. I've just came from C so I thought they are different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: thank you for those links, I am looking at them. This is the project from my school and it asks us to re-implement iterator_traits, I think it's for educational purpose. 
I did my version of iterator by redefining the required functions and overloading operators as you said. 
But then I read the project it requires to do other way with iterator_traits.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like this**

```
template<class T>
class VecIter : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
{
    public:
typedef T                                                   iterator_type;
typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag                     iterator_category;
typedef typename iterator_traits<T>::value_type             value_type;
typedef typename iterator_traits<T>::difference_type        difference_type;
        typedef typename iterator_traits<T>::pointer                pointer;
        typedef typename iterator_traits<T>::reference              reference;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).